# Need help building JSONObject java

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to build the following json object in java dynamically, for example, if the WARN object doesn't exist, add it or any other one followed by adding a new label message object to the sub array.

This is an example of what I'm trying to dynamically build.

```
{
  "warnings" : [
    {
      "WARN" : [
        {
          "label" : "Label Goes Here",
          "message" : "Message Goes Here"
        },
        {
          "label" : "Label Goes Here2",
          "message" : "Message Goes Here2"
        }
      ],"title" : "Please review the following warnings"
    },
    {
      "NOTIFICATION" : [
        {
          "label" : "Label Goes Here3",
          "message" : "Message Goes Here3"
        },
        {
          "label" : "Label Goes Here4",
          "message" : "Message Goes Here4"
        }
      ],"title" : "Please review the following warnings"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the what I've tried.

```
public class Warning {
    warningTypes = new JSONObject();
}

private JSONObject warningTypes;    

public Warning() {

public Warning(WarningType warningType, String label, String message) {
        this.warningType = warningType;
        this.label = label;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void add(WarningType warningType, String label, String message) {
        addToJSON(warningType, new JSONObject("label",label,"message",message));        
    }

    private void addToJSON(WarningType warningType, JSONObject jsonObj) {       
        if(warningTypes.has(warningType.name())) {
            JSONArray array = warningTypes.getJSONArray(warningType.name());   
            array.put(jsonObj);
        } else {

            warningTypes.put(warningType.name(), new JSONArray(jsonObj));
        }
    }

    public JSONObject toJSON() {
        return new JSONObject("warnings", new JSONArray(warningTypes));
    }

}
```

However this is my outcome which you can see is incorrect. I'm unable to add the title do to the fact my warningTypes are being but into a single object.

```
{
  "warnings" : [
    {
      "WARN" : [
        {
          "label" : "Label Goes Here",
          "message" : "Message Goes Here"
        },
        {
          "label" : "Label Goes Here2",
          "message" : "Message Goes Here2"
        }
      ],
      "NOTIFICATION" : [
        {
          "label" : "Label Goes Here3",
          "message" : "Message Goes Here3"
        },
        {
          "label" : "Label Goes Here4",
          "message" : "Message Goes Here4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I can not figure out how to build this object dynamically, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON you are trying to create does not have the same key. Following code will give you the desired output. Refactor the parts into methods as necessary.

Code:

```
public static class Message {
        private String label;
        private String message;

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public String getLabel() {
            return label;
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public void setLabel(String label) {
            this.label = label;
        }
    }

    public static enum WarningType {
        WARN, NOTIFICATION
    }

    public static class Warning {

        WarningType type;
        List<Message> messages;
        String title;

        public WarningType getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(WarningType type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public void setMessages(List<Message> messages) {
            this.messages = messages;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public List<Message> getMessages() {
            return messages;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
    }

    public static class Warnings {
        List<Map<String, Object>> warnings;

        public List<Map<String, Object>> getWarnings() {
            return warnings;
        }

        public void setWarnings(List<Map<String, Object>> warnings) {
            this.warnings = warnings;
        }

        public void setWarningsInMap(List<Warning> warningList) {
            warnings = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Warning each : warningList) {
                Map<String, Object> m = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                m.put(each.getType().name(), each.getMessages());
                m.put("title", each.getTitle());
                warnings.add(m);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        List<Warning> warningList = new ArrayList<>();

        Warning warn = new Warning();
        warn.setType(WarningType.WARN);

        List<Message> warnMessages = new ArrayList<>();

        Message m = new Message();
        m.setLabel("Label Goes Here");
        m.setMessage("Message Goes Here");
        warnMessages.add(m);

        m = new Message();
        m.setLabel("Label Goes Here2");
        m.setMessage("Message Goes Here2");
        warnMessages.add(m);

        warn.setMessages(warnMessages);

        warn.setTitle("Please review the following warnings");

        warningList.add(warn);

        Warning notification = new Warning();
        notification.setType(WarningType.NOTIFICATION);

        List<Message> notificationMessages = new ArrayList<>();

        m = new Message();
        m.setLabel("Label Goes Here3");
        m.setMessage("Message Goes Here3");
        notificationMessages.add(m);

        m = new Message();
        m.setLabel("Label Goes Here4");
        m.setMessage("Message Goes Here4");
        notificationMessages.add(m);

        notification.setMessages(notificationMessages);

        notification.setTitle("Please review the following warnings");

        warningList.add(notification);

        Warnings w = new Warnings();
        w.setWarningsInMap(warningList);

        String s = new ObjectMapper().defaultPrettyPrintingWriter().writeValueAsString(w);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Output:

```
{
  "warnings" : [ {
    "WARN" : [ {
      "message" : "Message Goes Here",
      "label" : "Label Goes Here"
    }, {
      "message" : "Message Goes Here2",
      "label" : "Label Goes Here2"
    } ],
    "title" : "Please review the following warnings"
  }, {
    "NOTIFICATION" : [ {
      "message" : "Message Goes Here3",
      "label" : "Label Goes Here3"
    }, {
      "message" : "Message Goes Here4",
      "label" : "Label Goes Here4"
    } ],
    "title" : "Please review the following warnings"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: what dependencies are you using to get this working? I like your approach.

Comment: You can use a nice library like Jackson to serialize / deserialize POJO's.

Comment: I like google GSON. See my answer to very brief example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [link](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) to a comprehensive guide.

If you want less work, you can use **Google GSON** to serialize POJOs to JSON objects. GSON can serialize POJOs, Arrays, Lists, Maps, other collections and will automatically differentiate between numbers and strings. This allows for better object oriented designs and lets you defer serializing to JSON objects up to the GSON. You don't have to worry about dynamically modifying JSONs, just dynamically modify the POJOs. Say you have some objects:

```
public class Warnings {
  @SerializedName("WARN")
  private Warn[] warns;
  @SerializedName("NOTIFICATION")
  private Notification[] notifications;

  public WARN[] getWARN(){...}

  public void setWarn(WARN[] warns){...}
  ...
}

public class Warn {
  private String message;
  private String label;
  ... // setters & getters
}

public class Notification {
  private String message;
  private String label;
  ... // setters & getters
}
```

you get the point

Then you can serialize it so:

```
Warnings someWarnings = new Warnings();
// Populate warnings
Gson gson = new Gson();
// Serialize
String jsonString = gson.toJson(someWarnings);
// Deserialize
Warnings sameWarinings = gson.fromJson(jsonString);
```